# Reset sort of KnpPaginator

Tags: symfony, knppaginator

I am looking for a method that resets the sort of the KnpPaginator Bundle, I am always blocked on 3 position, the first without any sort, the second in ascending sort and the third in descending sort, however, when I put a Sort I can not cancel it I have to keep be sort descending or the reverse. Is there a way to allow the user to return to the unsorted state?

Regards,

Comment: Shouldn't it be enough to remove the responsible url parameter? Meaning, place a link to the current page without it.

Comment: I see what you mean, but i was quiet sure that the way i'm looking for do exist, if not i will add a link ^^. Thank you for answering !